# Is there any way to run a suitescript on Home page?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm new to Netsuite SuiteScript, and I'm searching for a way to run a SuiteScript on the Home page (or any page that does not display a specific record.

Thanks,
Quan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Portlet that would be displayed as a widget on the Dashboard. Other than that, pages like search results, record lists, and others are *not* scriptable.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.